# Can a set be closed without its limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces

By definition, a set **A** is closed if it contains all of its accumulation(limit) points.

St **A = A'**

Also, a set is closed if it is the closure of the set.

where **A = ClosureA = A∪A'**

What happens if the accumulation points of the set is empty? is that set automatically open or closed?

Is the closure of a set without an accumulation point closed or open?is the closure of every set always closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate, possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593186/what-closure-of-a-given-subset-really-is/3593194#3593194

Answer (score 2):

If a set has no limit points it is closed.

The closure of a set is always closed.  By definition, one way to do it is that the closure is the smallest closed set containing a set.  Or, it's the intersection of all closed sets containing it.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes.

In [general-topology](/questions/tagged/general-topology), the closure of a set $A$ is defined to be the intersection of every closed set containing $A$. Since unions of open sets are open, this means intersection of closed sets are closed. The closure of $A$ is therefore the unique closed set $\overline{A}$ such that, for any closed set $B$, we have
$$A \subseteq B \implies \overline{A} \subseteq B.$$

In [real-analysis](/questions/tagged/real-analysis), one of several equivalent definitions of "closure" may be taught. In your case, it's $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$. We can show this is closed (in the sense that convergent sequences in $A$ converge to a limit in $A$) like so:

Suppose $a_n \in A \cup A'$ converges to $a \in \Bbb{R}$. I claim that there is a sequence $b_n \in A$ converging to the same limit. For every $n$ such that $a_n \in A$, we define $b_n = a_n \in A$. If $a_n \in A' \setminus A$, then there must be a point $b_n \in A$ such that $|a_n - b_n| < \frac{1}{n}$. So, for any $n$, we have
$$|a_n - b_n| \le \frac{1}{n} \implies a_n - \frac{1}{n} \le b_n \le a_n + \frac{1}{n}.$$
Note that the bounds on $b_n$ each tend to $a$, so by squeeze theorem, $b_n \to a$.

Now, if $a \in A$, then $a \in A \cup A'$, and we are done. If $a \notin A$, then $b_n \neq a$ for all $n$, hence $a \in A' \subseteq A \cup A'$. Either way, $A \cup A'$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Does Tom Hanks live with all his pet elephants?  What if Tom Hanks doesn't have any pets elephants?  Then does Tom Hanks live with all his pet elephants or doesn't he?

To a mathematician the the answer to "Does Tom Hanks live with all his pet elephants" is YES.  To say, "No, Tom Hanks doesn't live with all of his pet elephants" means that there is at least one pet elephant Tom Hanks doesn't live with.  But that is not the case.

So can a set be closed without *its* limit points.  For a set to be "without" *its* limit points means, there must be at least one limit point of the set that is not in the set.  And by definition, this means the set isn't closed because a set being closed means it *does* contain all it's limit point.

But that doesn't mean the set *HAS* any limit points.  If a set, (say for example the set $\mathbb Z$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric-- $\mathbb Z$ does not have any limit points-- none) doesn't have any limit points at all, then the set *IS* closed.

Because the answer to "Does $\mathbb Z$ contain all its limit points"  is "YES". $\mathbb Z$ does not have any limit points so there are no limit points that $\mathbb Z$ does not contain, so it is true that $\mathbb Z$ contains all its limit points.

So $\mathbb Z$ is closed.